# Is there a Trigger.IO API call to find out what platform version and Reload stream Id in my mobile app?

Tags: trigger.io

I want to track the Trigger.IO API platform version and Reload stream ID that my mobile ecommerce app is running when it submits an order. Is there an API call I can use to query this information when my app is running ?

Comment: Currently, no - is this so you can track usage numbers for Reload updates? We had planned on this use case being satisfied by the active users count & graphs - are we missing something there?

Comment: See my answer below. Yes I want to track reload updates but with my own analytics solution.

Answer (score 2):

James, yes I want to track usage numbers for Reload updates, but I want the data submitted to my own analytics solution. When the client submits an order I want to be able to do something like this :

```
function sendOrder (order) {

  var client = {};
  client.userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
  if (forge.is.android()) client.platform = "android"
  else if (forge.is.ios()) client.platform = "ios";
  client.packager = {name:"forge"};

  // ASSUME there is a new `gestalt` API to query the Trigger.IO client
  client.packager.version = forge.gestalt.platformVersion;
  client.packager.reloadId = forge.gestalt.reload.id;

  ajax.send(order, callback);

}
```

Comment: note, the gestalt API call does not exist. Its for illustration only.